# Removing blank space from a string

Tags: regex, excel, vba

How do I remove a blank space in a return string?

I am using in-cell functions in Excel. I find text in a string and move it to another place in the same string.

My results include an extra blank space that I want to remove.

Sample text string:

```
999999 - Blah Blah Blah 8888 blah blah
```

Desired result is:

```
999999 (8888) - Blah Blah Blah blah blah
```

My actual result is (note the extra blank space at 3rd Blah)

```
999999 (8888) - Blah Blah Blah  blah blah
```

Here is my current relevant code:

```
strPattern = "^(\d{6} )(\- )(\D+)(\d{4})"
strReplace = "$1($4) $2$3"
```

How do I deal with this either through my strPattern definition and/or strReplace definition?

Comment: Remove the space from `strReplace`, and add one to the last group of `strPattern`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may adjust your regex pattern to match as few non-digit symbols before optional whitespace chars as possible:

```
^(\d{6} )(- )(\D*?)\s*(\d{4})
                ^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/V3xAlP/2)

**Details**

- `^` - start of the string
- `(\d{6} )` - Group 1: six digits
- `(- )` - Group 2: a hyphen and a space
- `(\D*?)` - Group 3: any 0+ chars other than digits, but as few as possible as the `*?` quantifier is lazy (the quantified pattern is only tried and expanded when the subsequent patterns fail to match)
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespace chars
- `(\d{4})` - Group 4: four digits.